# How does the preferance of biotic process for right handed molecules suggest we do not live in euclidean space?

Tags: biology

At around 33:20 to 33:37 of [this video](https://youtu.be/0uUawrIRLbQ?t=2014), It is said that **biotic processes prefer right-handed molecules** and **this preference** is one **which can not exist in regular euclidean space**.

Sure I've heard about all the curved space-time stuff in relativity but how on earth does the preference for certain handed molecules by biological process relate to the nature of ambient space?

For reference, here is a definition of Euclidean space from Britannica:

> Euclidean space, In geometry, a two- or three-dimensional space in which the axioms and postulates of Euclidean geometry apply; also, a space in any finite number of dimensions, in which points are designated by coordinates (one for each dimension) and the distance between two points is given by a distance formula.

Comment: The only way would be the space having a hand itself. No idea if this makes even sense. And it should be handed at least at molecular scale. The existence of stereoisomers seems to preclude that. It should be something imposed by external conditions, in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

Left and right hand figure is same in  Euclidean space, just take a shape L, if right hand and  left hand almost identical in Euclidean space, now imagine that in non Euclidean space, eg, geodesic the same L shape both horizontal and vertical segment of L shape  is bend inwards and now imagine is left hand image  both arms of L bend outwards,(if imagine the same plane) biological molecules cannot form by combining both left handed and right handed molecule because of this , so they prefer either left hand or right handedness   that is exactly seen in nature . If we live in Euclidian world  both left and right hand molecule  has no difference and easy to combine , but since not, we seen a specific preference for either right or left handed molecule .